# After installing both wine and mono, I am still having an issue running a .exe in linux

Tags: software-installation, wine, mono, error-handling

I am trying to install the game Orcish Inn. I installed wine a while back and after trying to run OrcishInnLauncher.exe with wine, it said that I needed to install mono in order to run .NET applications. So I installed mono and ran into this issue:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No valid icon entry were found.
  at System.Drawing.Icon.InitFromStreamWithSize (System.IO.Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadNonPredefinedValue (System.Type exp_type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadValueVer2 (Int32 type_index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadResourceValues (ResourceCacheItem[] store) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator.FillCache () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator..ctor (System.Resources.ResourceReader readerToEnumerate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.ReadResources () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObjectInternal (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain:.ctor ()
  at OrcishInnLauncher.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No valid icon entry were found.
  at System.Drawing.Icon.InitFromStreamWithSize (System.IO.Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadNonPredefinedValue (System.Type exp_type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadValueVer2 (Int32 type_index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadResourceValues (ResourceCacheItem[] store) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator.FillCache () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator..ctor (System.Resources.ResourceReader readerToEnumerate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.ReadResources () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObjectInternal (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) OrcishInnLauncher.FormMain:.ctor ()
  at OrcishInnLauncher.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I am not very fluent in linux or mono so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ehm. this has nothing to do with Linux and probably not with mono either but with wine and dotnet. I would advice to ask this on a wine forum. For us to even be able to attempt to help you need to include information about your system (wine version, mono version, dotnet version etc). This could be as simple as you using  a too old version of any of these. You need dotnet 4.5.  Have you?

Comment: Do you use wine or mono to launch that? It's just that here is a wine-mono, and just mono. If you're launch the app with `wine`, then it is wine-mono — that should work. I'm not sure though for the plain `mono`.